# Using different headers with different headheights

Tags: fancyhdr, header

I'm writing a report and I'm using two different headers. I guess the "titlepage" header is occupying a lot of space, so I get the "headheight too small" message and the IDE changes all of the headspaces. I just can't seem to get it to properly distinguish between the two. So as a result, I got big space over my header in all of the document. I tried different orders, different usage of \pagstyle and \thispagestyle, but nothing works. The best solution was somethine with \pagestyle{fancy}, it removed the space in the document but also my titlepage header (which took me a while to figure out). I originally used the empty pagestyle, too but it makes only little difference. So how do I get rid of the blank space and get to keep all the good stuff?
Seems to be complicated, until now I could figure out this s$#* myself.
Cheers and thanks in advance

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[top=1cm,includeheadfoot, bottom=2.7cm, left=3cm, right=2cm,headheight=12pt, headsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[numbib, nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage[font=normalsize, textfont=it, labelsep=endash,width=.8\textwidth]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, sorting=nyt, citestyle=authoryear-comp, maxcitenames=2, sortcites=ynt, uniquename=init, giveninits=true, maxbibnames=9]{biblatex}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{1cm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[style=german]{csquotes}
\addbibresource{universal_bib.bib}
\fancypagestyle{titlepage}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \setlength{\headsep}{7cm}
    \lhead{\includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=c]{FAK_WZW_CMYK.pdf}~\parbox[c]{2cm}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont Wissenschaftszentrum \\ Weihenstephan}}
    \rhead{\includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=c]{TUM_blau.pdf}}
    }
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}
\rhead{\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}} 
\lhead{} %left head empty
\cfoot{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}
\rhead{\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}} 
\lhead{} %left head empty
\cfoot{\thepage}
\title{\textbf{sometitle} \\
\vspace{1cm}
\large Sometitle}
\author{someone }
\date{\today}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{titlepage}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\section{Einleitung}
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

Comment: What a weird idea to have a hearder in a title page?!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into something similar at the place I teach, since it is state-run and needs to have a special header on the first page.

Since you use the `geometry` and `fancyhdr` packages, you can define two different header styles (which you did) and adapt the geometry to the large header (you did that directly, but it can also be done with `\geometry{<your title page geometry>}`).

The key command would be to add a `\newgeometry{<your text page geometry>}` at the end of your title page, since this will automatically cause a page break. So you could have something like this:

```
...
\usepackage{geometry}
   \geometry{<title page geometry>}
...
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{titlepage}
\maketitle
\newgeometry{<text page geometry>}
...
```

At this point the geometry should be that of the text page. Two things though:

1. some classes (such as `book`) have precise instructions on where to place the TOC, especially if options such as `twosides` are active (since I don't know the class you're using);
2. if you need to have a whole page as a title, it might be more productive to make the header a part of the code for the title page, so that you would not need to bother with `geometry` tinkering (probably something @Bernard is alluding to).

Comment: Man, thanks a lot.. I did the geometry thing but only in part, so I got what I wanted but the error messages are still there. If they bother me, I guess I can do the exact changes you proposed, I'm sure they'll work. But for now, it works just fine. Yes, I actually thought of integrating the header into the title page, but I gave it up soon. Already put too much work in all of it. Thanks again

Comment: Concerning the `headheight too small` errors, it might be good to correct the page geometry, as LaTeX will try to compensate, and not always in a smart way...

Comment: Also, the problem in your code might be easier to spot if you use a _mininal working example_ or _MWE_ with only the code required to produce the desired error or function.